# Setting AlertDialog Text Freezes UI Thread

Tags: android, google-api

I have an about screen in my app that opens in an AlertDialog, in which I include the text from Google's open source API license. However, it takes almost 30 seconds to load the AlertDialog, and doing so often freezes the UI thread.

```
private void about() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new  AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("About ...");
    builder.setNeutralButton("Close",null);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApi=GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    String text=googleApi.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(getContext());
    String str=getResources().getString(R.string.about_message);
    str+=text;
    builder.setMessage(str);
    builder.show();
}
```

**EDIT**: The line that is causing this lag is the one that sets the dialog's text.

Note: I have already tried running the whole thing in an AsyncTask, and doing so did not change anything.

Comment: If you do a debug print between every line you can find out which line exactly is causing the app to hang

Comment: I've done that- it's the one that sets the text

Comment: "I have already tried running the whole thing in an AsyncTask, and doing so did not change anything" - using an AsyncTask won't make the method execute faster, but will solve the problem with blocked UI thread. As the call, I assume, is a network request, there's not a lot you can do to speed it up.

Comment: The part that takes long is not the network request, it's filling the AlertDialog with text.

Comment: Are you using a real device to test? Emulators are notorious for lagging and, if it is a long string, could cause major lag.

Comment: @TheAnonymous010  I'm using a device that is usually faster than average devices.

Comment: I don't think loading a license for `About` from a network is a good idea. Why don't you load it from assets? or try something easier like using [AboutLibraries](https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries)?

Comment: @isnotmenow, this is what was recommended by Google Developers:
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having this problem, one solution that works is to prevent the activity from overlaying another activity (if it uses Theme.Dialog, remove that). While this does not completely speed it up, it prevents the UI thread from being frozen for as long.